# Getting error in calling web service using ajax in jquery +jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am calling login web service.But I am not able to check what I will get from server .
I got this

```
**http://isuite.c-entron.de/CentronService/REST
                Username:         qus
                Password:          1**
```

I check on browser **http://isuite.c-entron.de/CentronService/REST&&Username=qus?Password=         1**

But not getting any thing.

Secondly I used ajax like this
404 will get .Is this way to calling web service.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        //event handler for submit button
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            //collect userName and password entered by users
            var userName = $("#username").val();
            var password = $("#password").val();

            //call the authenticate function
            authenticate(userName, password);
        });
    });

    //authenticate function to make ajax call
    function authenticate(userName, password) {
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            //the url where you want to sent the userName and password to
            url: "http://isuite.c-entron.de/CentronService/REST",
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            //json object to sent to the authentication url
            data: '{"Username": "' + userName + '", "Password" : "' + password + '"}',
            success: function () {
                //do any process for successful authentication here
            }
        })
    }
```

Here is fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/LsKbJ/1/

Comment: Probably SOP -- Check your console, do you see a Same Origin Policy error?

Comment: yes how to remove this error

Comment: any suggestion of this question

Comment: first of all there is no endpoint like the one in your fiddle. Are you looking for this? http://isuite.c-entron.de/CentronService/REST/help/operations/Login also the login parameters are different. `{
 "Ticket":"String content",
 "Data":{
  "Application":"String content",
  "Device":"String content",
  "LoginKind":0,
  "Password":"String content",
  "Username":"String content"
 }
}`

Comment: according to their [help page](http://isuite.c-entron.de/CentronService/REST/help) the rest url is REST/login for login, also their [reference page](http://isuite.c-entron.de/CentronService/REST/help/operations/Login#request-json) shows how you are supposed to format the request, also looks like they do not use CORS so probably need server side script to do this, for instance like using php and curl.

Comment: @naveen may be you are right how to do that

Answer (score 0):

try using crossDomain: true in ajax. Also, your data part was wrong. I corrected it below:

```
$.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        //the url where you want to sent the userName and password to
        url: "http://isuite.c-entron.de/CentronService/REST",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        //json object to sent to the authentication url
        data: {Username: userName, Password: password},
        success: function () {
            //do any process for successful authentication here
        }
    })
```

Comment: Also, ajax means asynchronous calls, why are you using async: false?